# Can the accept header be changed through the PHP library?

Tags: quickbooks-online

We are using the Consolibyte QuickBooks Online API PHP Library and are retrieving the **raw response** that we provide/bounce to a client. The response is currently in XML format, we'd like it to be JSON to make the transaction faster.

Can the `Accept` header be `application/json`? Or the library only supports XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently we only support XML. We don't support JSON quite yet.